# How to query RethinkDB based on a list of IDs

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Suppose I have the following table in RethinkDB:

[image]

I would like to query based on a list of IDs, for example the first two. It seems like the [getAll](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) function should do this, but I can't seem to get it to work:

[image]

The query returns no results, even though I copy-pasted the IDs from those shown on the previous screen grab. Is this not the correct way to use `getAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [args](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/args/) for this:

```
r.db("sensor_db).table("sensor_data").getAll(r.args([id1, id2]))
```

or you can write query without `[]`:

```
r.db("sensor_db).table("sensor_data").getAll(id1, id2,...)
```